# Copying rows to another worksheet based on a search on a grid of tags

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a problem with Excel that I was hoping someone could help me with.

I have a table where between columns K & Q are a number of tags. What I would like to do is have a function or a macro or something that will allow me to look within all these tags and copy any rows that contain a specific word to another worksheet.

e.g.

```
       I           J        K          L         M           N              O     etc. 
1      blah        blah     funding    blah      blah        blah           blah
2      funding     blah     blah       blah      blah        blah           blah
3      blah        blah     blah       blah      blah        blah           blah
4      blah        blah     blah       blah      blah        blah           blah
5      blah        blah     blah       blah      blah        funding        blah
6      blah        blah     funding    blah      blah        blah           blah
```

There is other information in columns A to H that I will also need to copy across, but do not want to include in the search. So in this scenario, I would like to be able to search for the tag 'funding' and therefore copy rows 1, 2, 5 & 6 to a different worksheet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code. I give credit to tompols from this forum (I based my code off this):
http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-242360-copy-row-if-a-range-of-column-matches-a-value

**UPDATE**:
Code rewritten to be more effecient with some fantastic points from *Jean-François Corbett* implemented (thanks!). I also added a message box at the end that reports how many rows were copied over.

I customized the code to do what you needed it to do. What happens when you run the macro (make sure you aren't on sheet 2) is that a box appears. Enter the word you want to filter by (in your case funding), and it will look through K:Q for cells that contain it. It will copy the entire column when it finds a match into sheet 2.

```vb
Sub customcopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastLine As Long
Dim findWhat As String
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

findWhat = CStr(InputBox("Enter the word to search for"))
lastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

j = 1
For i = 1 To lastLine
    For Each cell In Range("K1:Q1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
            toCopy = True
        End If
    Next
    If toCopy = True Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    toCopy = False
Next

i = MsgBox(((j - 1) & " row(s) were copied!"), vbOKOnly, "Result")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Accepting answers (I noticed you are new here): If this works for you, please click the arrow that appear on the upper left to accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: +1 but building cell addresses using string concatenation is bad practice. Could use e.g. `Range("K1:Q1").Offset(i-1, 0)` instead. Also `Range("A65536")` is Excel 2003-specific. There is a way around this using `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`.

Comment: Admittingly, I didn't look over the code too much while altering it. Thanks for the great advice!

Comment: Took your advice for the new version of the code. I ended up using ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count instead of activesheet.rows.count, though. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try [recording a macro](http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-how-to-excel-macro-recorder.html) with the following steps:

1. select the columns where you want to search (`K` and `Q` if i understood well)
2. perform a search with a sample tag
3. copy the row you found
4. paste it to the other Sheet

you will then have a first sample of code to start with.

see [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/beyond_the_macro_recorder/) for some tips on how to clean up the code